# Translate "Add to Cart" button on Recently Viewed widget

Tags: magento2.4.3, widget, translate

I think "Add to Cart" button recently viewed is hard coded.
Can anyone confirm this?

I did find a guide about changing the words in app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_CatalogWidget/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml but the codes he is referring to does not match what i have.

Comment: Hi there , so you want to change the add-to-cart button text only for recently viewed widget , is that your whole requirement or is it okay if that text changes in all places wherever the add-to-cart button shows ?

Comment: I want all Add to cart buttons to be changed to a Norwegian word, I have manage to translate all other buttons except the one for the recently viewed widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The add to cart button for the Recently Viewed Widget on magento 2 (from version 2.2 to the latest version 2.4.5) is now set to "Add To Cart" instead of "Add to Cart". I think this is a mistake, I'll create an issue for that and create a pull request to fix that.

So, you have to add a translated record for "Add To Cart":

"Add To Cart","Norwegian"

Comment: I can confirm that this worked, thank you so much!

Comment: I don't know if I need to create another ticket for this, but how do I translate the "cancel" button when you remove an item from minicart?

Comment: @Jan-petterHavna you can translate that "Cancel" button like all other words:


"Cancel","TranslatedWord"

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work :S I will make another ticket for it. Thanks

Comment: @Jan-petterHavna I've tested and it works. Make sure your translated words are case-sensitive: "Cancel" instead of "cancel". If you can't make it works, in another ticket, please describe what you tried to translate this text, I'll help.